# Добавление массива в mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

Создаю корзину и возник вопрос: сохраняю товары в корзине, из базы они списываются в нее. Но если я передумал их добавлять, нужно очистить корзину одним кликом, а не по одному товару и данные вписать обратно в таблицу. Выборку по количеству и id  я делаю с помощью цикла и получаю набор цифр.А вот как мне потом эти цифры рассортировать и отправить в базу для перезаписи?

```js
window.onload = function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.clear_basket').on('click', function(){
  var id = "";
  var quntity = "";
  $('.num_id').each(function(){
   id += $(this).val() + " ";
  });
  $('.b_quntity').each(function(){
   quntity += $(this).val() + " ";
  });
  console.log(id);
  console.log(quntity);
  });
 });
};
```

Вот сделал такой вывод, но возникла другая проблема. Как сделать отработку Ajax запроса после каждой отработки вывода массива each ( id1 -> quntity1 -> Ajax, id2 -> quntity2 -> Ajax, .... и т.д.)?

```js
window.onload = function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.clear_basket').on('click', function(){
  var id = "";
  var quntity = "";
  $('.num_id').each(function(){
   id = $(this).val();
   quntity = $(this).closest('div.b_list').find('.b_quntity').val();
    console.log(id);
    console.log(quntity);
   }); 
    $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/MyShop/php/product-basket-clear.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{id:id, quntity:quntity},
     success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
    }
   });
  }); 
 });
};
```

Comment: Я бы сделал со стороны API-БД интерфейс "очистить корзину" по которому бы в БД просто удалялись все записи из текущей корзины и не передавал бы списка id.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ подсказали на другом форуме. Может кому пригодится.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.clear_basket').on('click', function(){
  //var id = "";
  var quntity = "";
  var i = 0;
  var num = $('.num_id');
  (function func(){
   var id = num.eq(i).val();
   quntity = num.eq(i).closest('div.b_list').find('.b_quntity').val();
    $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/MyShop/php/product-basket-clear.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{id:id, quntity:quntity},
     success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
      if(num.length>++i) {func();}
    }
   });
    console.log(id);
    console.log(quntity);
   })();
   
  }); 
 });
};
```